# List all tables that are currently published for replication MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, replication, publish-subscribe

I need to get a list of all tables that are published for replication from MS-SQL databases. Is there a system stored procedure or a query I could run to generate such a list?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE is_replicated = 1
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx) for is_replicated field:

> 1 = Table is published using snapshot
>   replication or transactional
>   replication.

Comment: This depends on the type of replication used. For snapshot you may need to check is_published = 1. MSDN: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3333c691-4426-476c-b7c4-f8f55068937a/difference-between-ispublished-and-isreplicated-columns-of-systables?forum=sqlreplication

Comment: I can confirm that in SQL server 2014/2016 (i do not have early version to test), for snapshot replication, [is_replicated] does not tell whether a table is replicated or not. You have to use [is_published]=1 to find a snapshot replication table.

Answer (score 26):

It's possible to query the `distribution` database to see what articles (tables/views/objects...) are published and which Publication they are from.

```
SELECT
     P.[publication]   AS [Publication Name]
    ,A.[publisher_db]  AS [Database Name]
    ,A.[article]       AS [Article Name]
    ,A.[source_owner]  AS [Schema]
    ,A.[source_object] AS [Object]
FROM
    [distribution].[dbo].[MSarticles] AS A
    INNER JOIN [distribution].[dbo].[MSpublications] AS P
        ON (A.[publication_id] = P.[publication_id])
ORDER BY
    P.[publication], A.[article];
```

Comment: Works on SQL Server 2008

Comment: It's pretty useful to query the [distribution] entities.  And if your articles are all in the same DB (at least, all the ones you want to identify), you can join to that DB's [dbName].sys.tables/objects/etc. meta-data views to show even more info about them, like "what type of object is it" (because you could have more than just tables replicating), or even "which column is the PK".  I'll try to post more on this when I have a chance.